# Resistance including temperature - tungsten

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, electrical-resistance

I am doing a paper on calculating temperatures of tungsten filament inside a halogen lamp. I have measured different voltage-current levels and calculated the resistance. Then, I have used formula $R=R_o(1+A\Delta T$) to deduce $\Delta T$. But my teacher told me to use $R=R_o(1+AT+BT^2)$. How does this second formula differ from the first and what are those $A$ and $B$? I suppose $A$ is the same coefficient from the first, but what is $B$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your teacher is the best resource for your particular problem. The changes in resistivity with temperature are parametrized in various ways, depending on for example the temperature range you are concerned with. In your case, it is likely that a simple linear extrapolation will not work, so you have been asked to add a quadratic term. It should be fairly simple to determine if a linear fit is sufficient for your lab or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table of  the resistivity of wolfram, ie: http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2004/DeannaStewart.shtml

If you MUST use the quadratic form, then calculate A and B from the values in the table.